# How can I get RMarkdown to recognize both fontsize and mainfont when converting to PDF?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

An Rmd file with the YAML headers:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "September 14, 2015"
output:
  pdfdocument:
    latexengine: xelatex
fontsize: 12pt
---
```

Correctly renders in 12 computer modern roman when converted to PDF in RStudio. If I add `mainfont`:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "September 14, 2015"
output:
  pdfdocument:
    latexengine: xelatex
fontsize: 12pt
mainfont: Helvetica
---
```

The PDF is rendered in Helvetica, but at 10 point. I can't get PDF output of 12pt non-CMR. Is there any way to do this?

I've also tried setting the YAML to `12pt` and putting `\usepackage{helvet}` in an external `.tex` file that gets included `in_header`, but I get 12pt CMR.

Answer (score 1):

I often encounter problems when trying to use Rmarkdown YAML commands to change font specs. For example, for me neither mainfont nor sansfont command worked to render in Helvetica, or maybe I just fail at figuring out the correct indentation in the YAML header. Besides, I guess you would need to give more information about which OS and R(markdown) Version you're using for someone to help you.

A solution that worked for me (64-bit Linux, R 3.1.2, Rmarkdown 0.7) using CTAN helvet package is this one (let me know it it works for you):

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "September 14, 2015"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{helvet}
  - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  - \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
output:
  pdf_document
fontsize: 12pt
---
```

I derived the solution from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121061/working-with-arial-or-helvetica-fonts).